# Moving up one directory in Python

Tags: python, directory

Is there a simple way to move up one directory in python using a single line of code? Something similar to `cd ..` in command line

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```py
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
C:\Python27
>>> os.chdir("..")
>>> print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
C:\
```

Answer (score 52):

Using [**`os.chdir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) should work:

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
```

Answer (score 18):

Obviously that os.chdir('..') is the right answer here. But just FYI, if in the future you come across situation when you have to extensively manipulate directories and paths, here is a great package (Unipath) which lets you treat them as Python objects: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unipath

so that you could do something like this:

```
>>> from unipath import Path
>>> p = Path("/usr/lib/python2.5/gopherlib.py")
>>> p.parent
Path("/usr/lib/python2.5")
>>> p.name
Path("gopherlib.py")
>>> p.ext
'.py'
```

Comment: In python3.4 the *pathlib* was introduced, which was meant to tackle the same problem (refer to my answer for more details).

Answer (score 16):

Well.. I'm not sure how portable os.chdir('..') would actually be. Under Unix those are real filenames. I would prefer the following:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
```

That gets the current working directory, steps up one directory, and then changes to that directory.

Comment: also, with slightly less typing, `os.chdir(os.path.pardir)`.

This answer is slightly more platform independent, but it is sort of a moot point because while you could imagine a platform that doesn't represent `..` as the parent directory, any platform that anyone currently uses (including both windows and UNIX) do represent it that way.

Comment: Yeah you're right! I just finished testing it on a windows box, and `..` works fine. I always expect so little of windows but it does sometimes surprise me :). Still, magic strings littering my code always bother me.

Comment: I agree, but just musing: I wonder if there will *ever* be a real system that doesn't use this particular convention.

Comment: I hope not. Unix 4 life.

Comment: how come this move one directory up? I don't understand by the code. What if I want to move two directories up?

Comment: You could try running each part of the code in a Python shell? It would demonstrate what is happening here. If you wanted to move two directories up, you would have to insert another call to `os.path.dirname`.

Comment: For the answer from @aestrivex, this works great. This also works if the [`.path` part is excluded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pardir): `os.chdir(os.pardir); print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 16):

In Python 3.4 *pathlib* was introduced:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/etc/usr/lib')
>>> p
PosixPath('/etc/usr/lib')
>>> p.parent
PosixPath('/etc/usr')
```

It also comes with many other helpful features e.g. for joining paths using slashes or easily walking the directory tree.

For more information refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or [this blog post](http://blog.danwin.com/using-python-3-pathlib-for-managing-filenames-and-directories/), which covers the differences between os.path and pathlib.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not exactly what OP meant as this is not super simple, however, when running scripts from Notepad++ the `os.getcwd()` method doesn't work as expected. This is what I would do:

```
import os

# get real current directory (determined by the file location)
curDir, _ = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

print(curDir) # print current directory
```

Define a function like this:

```
def dir_up(path,n): # here 'path' is your path, 'n' is number of dirs up you want to go
    for _ in range(n):
        path = dir_up(path.rpartition("\\")[0], 0) # second argument equal '0' ensures that 
                                                        # the function iterates proper number of times
    return(path)
```

The use of this function is fairly simple - all you need is your path and number of directories up.

```
print(dir_up(curDir,3)) # print 3 directories above the current one
```

The only minus is that it doesn't stop on drive letter, it just will show you empty string.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to move up multiple directories is [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path
    
full_path = "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\pathlib.py"
print(Path(full_path).parents[0])
print(Path(full_path).parents[1])
print(Path(full_path).parents[2])
print(Path(full_path).parents[3])

print([str(Path(full_path).parents[i]) for i in range(4)])
```

output:

```sh
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\Python37
C:\Program Files
C:\

['C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37', 'C:\\Program Files', 'C:\\']
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine Kim's answer with os:

```
p=Path(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(p.parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned path to variable and want to go up one directory.

```
p = os.getcwd()
up_dir = os.path.join(p, "..")
abs_path = os.path.abspath(up_dir)
```